# Why is the login shell environment variables different from the cron environment variables?

Tags: bash, shell, cron

In bash login shell, there are dozens of environment variables exists, such as follow:

```
HOSTNAME=myhost
TERM=screen
SHELL=/bin/bash
HISTSIZE=1000
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/20
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
USER=user
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$:/usr:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/local/lib64
DRC_ROOT=/home/ds
PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/user
PWD=/data/user
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
TMUX_PANE=%135
PS1=(dbrt_env) \[\e[37m\][\[\e[32m\]\u\[\e[32m\](\[\e[36m\]\[\e[37m\])\[\e[35m\]@\[\e[0m\]\h \[\e[33m\]\W\[\e[0m\]]\$ 
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
SHLVL=2
HOME=/data/user
LOGNAME=user
REALUSERNAME=
CVS_RSH=ssh
HISTTIMEFORMAT=%F %T
G_BROKEN_FILENAMES=1
_=/bin/env
.....
```

but in crontab job, the envrioment variables is really few:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
USER=user
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
PWD=/data/user
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
HOME=/data/user
LOGNAME=user
_=/usr/bin/env
```

what's the designing intent of the difference?

Why not make them the same?

Comment: Did you notice the difference in values of `SHELL` in both the cases, that's the reason why!, `cron` provides a minimalist  environment needed to be run by the `sh` shell and nothing extravagant

Comment: So is it possible to change the cron shell from sh to bash?

Comment: Yes you can by doing `SHELL=/bin/bash` as the first line of your `cron` job

Comment: I check the /bin/sh file of my system, it's a soft link to /bin/bash, IOW they are the same.

Comment: @Inian, ...you mean first line of the `crontab`.

Comment: @Bruce, even if it's a symlink, that doesn't mean they're the same. Bash turns off a bunch of features when it's invoked under the `sh` name (as in that mode its purpose is compatibility with the POSIX sh standard). See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html

Comment: you mean the bash binary file has decide wether to set the POSIX env by judged the name which is executed during execution?

Answer (score 1):

Cron uses a different shell (/bin/sh) to your login shell (/bin/bash).  The bash shell has various different files that it uses to set things up (`man bash` will give you the full details).

The best thing to do is not to try to get them to be the same (why does cron need PS1 etc.) rather create a script that has everything that you need in a controlled way and have cron use that.

If the environment that you want is in `/home/me/setupenv.sh` then add the following to the cron script and it will run it:

`. /home/me/setupend.sh`

Don't forget the leading `.` otherwise it will run the script in a different environment and the changes will be lost when the script ends.

Comment: Setting `SHELL=/bin/bash` in the first line of your crontab will cause bash to be used, but *won't* result in login-shell-only environment variables being exposed. As such, this answer seems... a bit misleading, inasmuch as it describes the use of `/bin/sh` as an immediate cause for the change in available variables.

Answer (score 1):

An interactive environment is expected to be heavily customized for an individual user's preferences. As such, there are several sources of extra environment variables present:

- PAM modules and other login-time sources (including, in the above case, environment variables set by SSH)
- `~/.bash_profile`, `/etc/profile`, and other scripts intended for login-shell use
- `~/.bashrc` and other scripts intended for interactive-shell initialization

By contrast, the noninteractive environment exposed to daemons (including `cron`) is expected to be *predictable* and *consistent* -- meaning that a script written on one machine should work on another. Pulling in an individual user's settings is contrary to this goal. Moreover, since there **is** no login shell involved in running `cron`, scripts which are only sourced by a login shell are never executed.

---

If you take a close look at the environment list you provided, **many** of them make no sense at all in a noninteractive shell:

- `TERM` only makes sense when there's a terminal.
- `TMUX_PANE` only makes sense when that terminal is tmux.
- `HISTSIZE` only makes sense when you have an interactive shell storing history.
- `SSH_TTY` only makes sense when you connected via ssh.
- `LC_ALL` specifies language and locale settings to use for communicating with the user who's operating the terminal.
- `PS1` specifies how to format an interactive prompt.

Etc. Etc. Etc.

---

If you need a variable exported when your crontab is run, specify it explicitly at the top of that crontab. This prevents settings made for the convenience of interactive users from breaking or modifying the behavior of background jobs.

Comment: I have understand it.Thank you very much!